# Как cделать рейтинг игроков? (java)

Tags: java

Есть код игры "Угадай число". Но рейтинг участников вывести не могу.Пробовала array.sort().  Проблема в том, что его необходимо выводить вместе с именами участников. Если отсортировать массив с результатами int, то как в таком же порядке отсортировать имена. 
Пробовала через min, но как каждый раз выводить минимальное число, не считая предыдущего.
Вообщем, запуталась. Помогите, плиз)

```
package guessthenumber;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GuessTheNumber {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        thePlay play1 = new thePlay();
        play1.play();
        System.out.println("Игроку по именем "+play1.thename+" понадобилось "+play1.attempts+" попыток.");

        thePlay play2 = new thePlay();
        play2.play();
        System.out.println("Игроку по именем "+play2.thename+" понадобилось "+play2.attempts+" попыток.");

        thePlay play3 = new thePlay();
        play3.play();
        System.out.println("Игроку по именем "+play3.thename+" понадобилось "+play3.attempts+" попыток.");

        int [] mas = new int[] {play1.attempts,play2.attempts,play3.attempts};
        String [] mas2 = new String[] {play1.thename,play2.thename,play3.thename};



/*int min = mas[0];
int temp = 0;
int h = 0;

while (h<mas.length){

  for(int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++){

            if(min > mas[i]){
                min = mas[i];
                temp=i;

            }

        }

h++;
    System.out.print(mas2[temp]+" - ");  
    System.out.print(min+" ");
}*/

        //Arrays.sort(mas);
        //for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
       // System.out.print(mas[i]+" ");
       // }




    }
}
class thePlay{
    int attempts;
    String thename;
    public void play(){

        Player play= new Player();
        play.Name();
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNum = random.nextInt(3);
        System.out.println("Компьютер загадал число от 0 до 3.");
        int i = 1;
        play.Number();

        while (play.numP!=randomNum){

             if(play.numP>randomNum) {
                System.out.println("Загаданное число меньше,попробуй ещё.");
                play.Number();
                i++;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Загаданное число больше,попробуй ещё.");
                play.Number();
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Ты угадал");

        attempts = i;
        thename = play.name;
    }   




    }


class Player{
    String name;
    int numP;

    public void Name(){
        System.out.println("Привет! Введи своё имя: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = scanner.nextLine();

    }

    public void Number(){
        System.out.print("Ты считаешь, что это число - ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        numP = scanner.nextInt();

    }
}
```

Comment: Должен быть один массив, а не два.

Comment: А как с делать с одним массивом? Как привязать имена к результатам?

Comment: В класс Player добавить поле с результатом.

Comment: Не мог ли бы вы прислать пример. Я добавила поле, но все равно не понимаю как к нему обращаться после сортировки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я немного поправил ваши переменные и произвел сортировку.

```
public class GuessTheNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        ThePlay play;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            play = new ThePlay();
            players.add(play.play());
            toConsole(players.get(i));
        }

        players.sort(Comparator.comparing(Player::getAttempts));
        players.forEach(GuessTheNumber::toConsole);
    }

    private static void toConsole(Player player) {
        System.out.println(player.toString());
    }

}

class ThePlay {
    private int attempts;
    private String playerName;
    private Player player;
    private int randomNum;

    public ThePlay() {
        attempts = 1;
        player = new Player();
        randomNum = new Random().nextInt(100);
        System.out.println(randomNum);
    }

    public Player play() {

        player.makeName();
        System.out.println("Компьютер загадал число от 0 до 3.");
        player.makeNumber();

        while (player.getNumber() != randomNum) {
            if (player.getNumber() > randomNum) {
                System.out.println("Загаданное число меньше,попробуй ещё.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Загаданное число больше,попробуй ещё.");
            }
            player.makeNumber();
            attempts++;
        }

        System.out.println("Ты угадал");
        player.setAttempts(attempts);
        return player;
    }

    public int getAttempts() {
        return attempts;
    }

    public void setAttempts(int attempts) {
        this.attempts = attempts;
    }

    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
}

class Player {

    private String name;
    private int number;
    private int attempts;

    public void makeName() {
        System.out.println("Привет! Введи своё имя: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public void makeNumber() {
        System.out.print("Ты считаешь, что это число - ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        number = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getAttempts() {
        return attempts;
    }

    public void setAttempts(int attempts) {
        this.attempts = attempts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Игроку по именем " + getName() + " понадобилось " + getAttempts() + " попыток.";
    }
}
```